# What does it mean if a recruiter does not come back to the applicant

Tags: recruitment

A recruiter tried to call me in response to my application to a position in his company. I was not available so he left me a voicemail asking me to call him back. I called back the same day and the next business day but he do not respond. I left him a voicemail.

Does this mean he already found another candidate?

Answer (score 2):

Don't read into things.

Sometimes you won't get a call back for a couple of days because the person you're trying to contact is busy.  Sometimes you won't get a call back because they're out sick or taking a day off.  Sometimes they find out that the hiring manager already filled the position.  Sometimes they're waiting for the hiring manager to reply to an email.  Sometimes they received hundreds of applications for the position and are working their way through them before calling people back.

In any case, the reason for the delay shouldn't affect your behavior.  You've called back already.  Give it a few days.  If you don't hear back, it may make sense to call again in a few days.  You should always operate on the assumption that they're not going to call back/ offer you the job/ etc. so you should be applying to other opportunities.

Comment: Jury duty, national guard call up, death in the family, ..., lots of possibilities.

Comment: And some recruiters are just plain rude.